# What is this: $(function() {?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this basically the same as `$(document).ready` or is this only run like this to ensure jQuery is there?

Maybe something else I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. `$(function() { ... });` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`.

See [the jQuery documentation for this handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Thanks.  you have no idea how hard it is to google that string.

Comment: @dubRun: All the top results for "document ready jquery" (omit quotes) are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

There is no difference as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the jQuery 1.5.1 source. The $(function(){}) shorthand uses the ready-function internally.

```
// HANDLE: $(function)
// Shortcut for document ready
} else if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) ) {
    return rootjQuery.ready( selector );
}
```